# Javascript: How to use eval() safely

Tags: javascript

I am building a little game and I've gotten to the point where I need to calculate data in the tips of abilities which is unique to each individual unit. So to do this I figured I'm gonna basically need a formula. I don't know if this is **the way** it's supposed to be done but here's what I've come up with

```
tip = 'Hurls a fire ball at your enemy, dealing [X] damage.';
formula = '5 * unit.magicPower * abilitylevel';
```

So  for each unit's tool tip I use

```
tip.replace('[X]', eval(formula))
```

Which appears to work fine, but what I'm concerned about is the safety of this code. It hasn't been once or twice that I've seen people discouraging the use of it. Are there any potential issues that may occur with the way I'm using `eval()`?

Comment: You'll want to use a library built specifically for doing math, or if you need more JavaScript functionality use a sandbox.  That's assuming that this formula is arbitrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as **you** control the input into `eval`, it's safe to use it. The concern comes in when you're using it to process input that you *don't* control. At that point, it becomes unsafe because it's a full JavaScript parser but people sometimes try to use it as just an expression evaluator (for instance, when parsing JSON from a source they don't control).

The other objection is that it's firing up a full JavaScript parser (and so in theory costly), but frankly unless you're doing this hundreds of thousands of times in a tight loop, it's not going to matter.

Comment: But saying that you can control anything in javascript is like saying you own gravity

Comment: @php_nub_qq: If you're doing `eval("5 * unit.magicPower * abilityLevel")`, and you define `unit` and the other variables, you're controlling the input. There's no magic someone can throw in that makes that unsafe.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In those cases though, there is no reason to use `eval()` at all.

Comment: @Brad: Yeah, use cases are very few and far between.

Answer (score 2):

`eval` is very dangerous if any of the expression is supplied by the user. If you're constructing it entirely from built-in components, it's not very dangerous. However, there are still usually better ways of accomplishing it, such as calling closures.

Comment: Arguably, it's not dangerous if the input comes from the *current* user; they could, after all, open the web console and do anything. But if you're using `eval` to evaluate input in a user's browser that comes from a *different* user, *that* becomes dangerous.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahhhh now I see. That opened my eyes a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule of thumb is to make sure that by default you pass **your** data/information through `eval()` only.

You can't stop someone with tools like Firebug if they want to mess with stuff obviously but that is what server-side validation is about.

Now if you're talking about server-side `eval()` then you really have to be careful. Unfortunately there are a lot of uncooperative people working on JavaScript and it's implementations in browsers so you'll be forced to use `eval()` in JavaScript, I've never had to use it in PHP.